# I want the redirection is similar to the google site

Tags: php, redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show different homepage based on the user's Country?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122169/how-to-show-different-homepage-based-on-the-users-country)

I have two site one is ".com" second is ".in" but, when the  user come from india i want to show  the ".in" and if the any user come from the other country i want show him only ".com".
is this type of redirection possible, how can i do this? this redirection is similar to the google site

Comment: This can be done with a redirect. How do you want to find out if a user comes from India?

Comment: Use IP address to find country and then redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of (or in addition to) looking at country of the IP address, you should inspect `Accept-Language` HTTP header (`$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` in PHP)

[PHP intl extension has methods that help parsing it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/locale.lookup.php).

This header usually contains language-country pairs, and this is something that user can configure, unlike their IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to guess the country based on the remote address of the user.

The following is a working solution, you'll have to work the redirection logic though:

```
$remoteAddr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$lookupUrl = sprintf('http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=%s', $remoteAddr);
$country = trim(file_get_contents($lookupUrl));

if ('IN' === $country)
{
    $newUrl = 'http://www.vaibhav-kipl.in/';

    header(sprintf('Location: %s', $newUrl));
    printf('<a href="%s">Moved.</a>', $newUrl);
    exit();
}
```

Take care that search engine robots from India are able to crawl the .com content as well however.