# fsockopen have errors : HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently and 404

Tags: php, fsockopen

I have used this code to open `whatismyipaddress.com`

```
$fp = fsockopen("whatismyipaddress.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 5);

if ($fp) {
    $url = "/";

    fputs($fp, "GET $url HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {whatismyipaddress.com}\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n");
    $resp = '';

    while(!feof($fp)) {
        $resp .= fgets($fp, 1024);
    }

    echo "$resp";
}
```

and i always can see this error

> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently Date: Tue, 29 Nov 2011 20:19:36 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) DAV/2 Location: http://whatismyipaddress.com/ MS-Author-Via: DAV Content-Length: 0 Connection: close Content-Type: text/html

Also i have used this code to open `whatismyipaddress.com/proxy-check`

```
$fp = fsockopen("whatismyipaddress.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 5);

if ($fp) {
    $url = "/proxy-check";

    fputs($fp, "GET $url HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {whatismyipaddress.com}\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n");
    $resp = '';

    while(!feof($fp)) {
        $resp .= fgets($fp, 1024);
    }

    echo "$resp";
}
```

and have this error

> HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found Date: Tue, 29 Nov 2011 20:32:07 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) DAV/2 Content-Length: 421 Connection: close Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
>   Not Found
>
> The requested URL /proxy-check was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>   Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) DAV/2 Server at {whatismyipaddress.com} Port 80

I'm sure, there is no any problem with the codes. i have tested it with many sites and i didn't get any problem

Please can anyone explain this problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: try `http://whatismyipaddress.com` (with http://)

Comment: Remove the `{}` surrounding the domain name in the `Host:` header in the request.

Comment: Please note from http://whatismyipaddress.com/terms-of-use:  "You may not use a script, agent, application or otherwise query this website in an automated fashion without prior written permission."

Comment: @Phoenix.Thanks i will take care with that.Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your script works fine. There are some errors. One is specific to HTTP, see this line of code:

```
fputs($fp, "GET $url HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {whatismyipaddress.com}\r\nCon ...
                                       ^                     ^
```

Remove those brackets, the HTTP protocol does not have any of those there, you need to provide a valid hostname. Solution:

```
fputs($fp, "GET $url HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: whatismyipaddress.com\r\nCon ...
```

Then the remote site will tell you need a user agent. Add it as an additional header:

```
fputs($fp, "GET $url HTTP/1.1\r
Host: whatismyipaddress.com\r
Connection: close\r
User-Agent: Florian der Fensterputzer\r\n\r\n");
```

This will do it. [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/45fAF4).

Comment: Thank you very very much hakre
My Best Regards.

Comment: Guys please wait...don't leave me

Comment: The problem with "Advanced Proxy Check" whatismyipaddress.com/proxy-check this page will check the hosting DNS IP not REMOTE_ADRR for the visitor.Deos it possible to do that ?

Comment: To get the IP address of your visitor (better the computer which accesses your script, e.g. a proxy), you can use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. Anyway that's only technical detail, compare with [How to show different homepage based on the user's Country?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2122169/367456). The service you are using (http://whatismyipaddress.com) is IMHO fooling it's visitors, so I won't offer any support for them.

Comment: I just wish to use there service to detect the visitor who using aproxy..i think this not possible by fsockopen right ?

Comment: You can't provide an IP address in form of a parameter as far as I can see, so it's not possible by `whatismyipadress.com`. `fsockopen` is only a function to open a socket and do a HTTP request, same as comparably `file_get_contents` or some curl stuff. So this is more related to the HTTP service you're using than the concrete function you use to use the HTTP service.

Comment: That is ok..Thank you hakre :)

Comment: Just to clarify: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` will contain the address you'd like to check, but the `wimipadrr.com/proxy-check` HTTP Service does not provide an IP parameter to make it particularly check for the IP address you like it to check (at least I guess so, I didn't really elaborated that service, as written I don't like to support them).

Comment: yes, i understand your point..by the way i have found something here http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php maybe i can connect by fsockopen by proxy ip and port :) and i will add the proxy ip $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']..i should try

Comment: Sure you can try to trick their script by mimicking "fakre" proxy headers. This probably works ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would try to use another user-agent in headers.
I'm sure they are blocking robots using some sort of header based protection.

Using curl:

```
$ curl -I 'http://whatismyipaddress.com'
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Tue, 29 Nov 2011 20:48:28 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) DAV/2
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

However, once trying a forced user agent it works:

```
$ curl -I -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:8.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0.1' 'http://whatismyipaddress.com'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 29 Nov 2011 20:49:24 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) DAV/2
Set-Cookie: pt=f737a9bb1a119dcec75073f11b05d213; expires=Wed, 30-Nov-2011 20:49:24 GMT
MS-Author-Via: DAV
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: This is correct, they block clients they think are bots such as curl, lynx, or requests with no user agent header.  He needs to spoof the request using a valid user agent from Firefox, Chrome, IE etc.

Comment: Thank you very very much Uzi & drew010
My Best Regards.