# How to detect visitor's country and display the right image or text?

Tags: php, html

Is there any way how to detect the visitor's country and display the right image?

Example: 
Visitor navigate to my website, website get the response he is from USA and the website will display 'usa.png' insead of 'default.png' ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show different homepage based on the user's Country?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122169/how-to-show-different-homepage-based-on-the-users-country)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553160/getting-visitors-country-from-their-ip   -  Try looking at this link

Answer (score 0):

With the IP, you can use the free database of Maxmind for compare Ip visitor : http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz